# Make dashed (or dotted) circle appear like powerpoint wheel animation

Tags: animation, mesh

How do you make a dashed or dotted circle appear like a powerpoint wheel animation? I would like to make an animation like the one below.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Please see array modifier which can duplicate a mesh from 1 to n times and have a rotation.  So array modifier with a rotating empty is a typical way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done procedurally pretty easily.

Just make a ring shaped object that has the desired dotted line width and give it this material:
[image]

The driver for the second input of the subtract node is `#(frame - 1) / 120`. The `120` is the number of frames for one rotation (at 60 fps this is two seconds).

[image]

[image]